# Finding a particular solution to a given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Got some issues with a question:

Let `y1`be a solution to the homogeneous diff.equation dy/dx + P(x)y = 0.
Derive a particular solution to the inhomogeneous dy/dx + P(x)y=f(x).

Can someone please help me to start with this question, no clue of how to start...

Comment: Hint: Integrating factor is a concept you might want to look up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

First, solve the associated homogeneous ODE :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y(x)=0$$
$$y(x)=c\:e^{-\int P(x)dx}=c\:y_1(x)$$
Second, replace the constant $c$ by an unknown function $u(x)$ :
$$y(x)=u(x)\:y_1(x)$$
Put it into the non-homogeneous ODE $\quad \frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y(x)=f(x)$

After simplification, you will obtain a simple homogeneous ODE to be solved for $u(x)$.